# Проблемы с memmove() Cи

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Это опять человек-кривые-руки.
Сегодня вот какой вопрос. Точнее два вопроса:
У меня есть этот кусок кода:

```
  int a = strlen(f)/2;
  memmove(str, a, 80);
```

Этот кусок кода исполняет это действо:
Двигает определённое кол-во символов за массив(как я понял).
Но, видимо мои понятия слишком далеки от реальности.
Консоль выдаёт это:
**Строка с �ушать:
�ушать, кушать я хочу

Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)**
И, да, кушать - искомое слово в программе. но не суть.
А вот теперь вопросы:
Первое:Почему происходит дамп?(я полагаю, из-за моего кривого понимания?)
Второе:Что это за г такое - �?
И, как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрим `memmove` -

```
void* memmove( void* dest, const void* src, size_t count );
```

И что вы передаете в качестве исходной строки? целое число. Т.е. у вас функция пытается в `str` (неизвестно как определенное) засунуть 80 байт, начиная с адреса, содержащегося в целом числе `a`...

Понятно, что ничего хорошего из этого не получается.

Comment: Спасибо) , А как исправить �?

Comment: Для начала дайте точное ТЗ, что вы хотите. Потому как без ТЗ получается, как правило, ХЗ... Догадаться, что вам нужно, из ваших двух строк у меня не получается.

Comment: Спасибо, но уже не надо) сам нашёл)